# Investigate whether the System Can be solved for $x,y,z$ in terms of $u,v,w$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Investigate whether or not the system

$
u(x,y,z) = x+xyz
$

$
v(x,y,z) = y + xy
$

$
w(x,y,z) = z+2x+3z^2
$

can be solved for $x,y,z$ in terms of $u,v,q$ near $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$

---

I'm not really sure how to even start on this question. I am not looking for someone to give me a full answer, but I just want some guidance on where to start.

Comment: Did you learn inverse function theorem or implicit function theorem?

Comment: I don't really have a good understanding of them. Especially inverse function theorem. I found this for implicit though, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtgTckGMuWE

Comment: Basically the incerse function theorem says that if $F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(p) = q$ and $Df_p$ is nonsingular, then $F$ is locally invertible.